# How do I determine if the ebpf program is tracepoint, rawtracepoint, kprobe, etc?

Tags: ebpf, bpf

root@master:/sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events# cat syscalls/sys_enter_openat/format
name: sys_enter_openat
ID: 651
format:

field:unsigned short common_type;   offset:0;   size:2; signed:0;
field:unsigned char common_flags;   offset:2;   size:1; signed:0;
field:unsigned char common_preempt_count;   offset:3;   size:1; signed:0;
field:int common_pid;   offset:4;   size:4; signed:1;
field:int __syscall_nr;    offset:8;   size:4; signed:1;
field:int dfd;  offset:16;  size:8; signed:0;
field:const char * filename;   offset:24;  size:8; signed:0;
field:int flags;    offset:32;  size:8; signed:0;
field:umode_t mode; offset:40;  size:8; signed:0;

print fmt: "dfd: 0x%08lx, filename: 0x%08lx, flags: 0x%08lx, mode: 0x%08lx", ((unsigned long)(REC->dfd)), ((unsigned long)(REC->filename)), ((unsigned long)(REC->flags)), ((unsigned long)(REC->mode))

how to know what prog type it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking at is the format for a tracepoint. It describes the structure of the context that will be passed to a potential `BPF_PROG_TYPE_TRACEPOINT` program if you were to attach it at this tracepoint. Tracepoint programs can only be attached to these pre-defined tracepoints in the kernel.

`BPF_PROG_TYPE_RAW_TRACEPOINT` programs can also attach at these same tracepoints but instead of getting the formatted context you will just get an array of 64-bit values representing the arguments. So you might have to do some additional work to parse them.

```c
struct bpf_raw_tracepoint_args {
       __u64 args[0];
};
```

`BPF_PROG_TYPE_KPROBE` programs can attach to at pretty much any function in the kernel. Exceptions are locations that are explicitly forbidden. But other factors like the inlining of functions can also make it hard to kprobe certain things. Like the raw tracepoint, you will not get any type information here, just raw register values and the ability to read the kernel memory within reason.

Comment: Yes, how do I know if I can write ebpf in kprobe or tracepoint? Maybe he doesn't support the above trace points, but he does support kprobe. How do I know?

Comment: tracepoint is more stable than kprobe. If I am writing an automated ebpf application, how can I be sure that the tracking method I get will work with tracepoint or raw_tracepoint?

Comment: Tracepoints are more stable than kprobes. However, both are designed as debugging tools and do not necessarily have the same stability guarantees as syscalls for example. For tracepoints you can test the contents of the exact path you already discovered to see if the system you are on is compatible. For kprobes it is more difficult, you could attempt to find the function you are trying to trace in the vmlinux BTF and check its signature. This is definitely one of the big challenges with eBPF and tracing

Comment: this directory always use tracepoint ? /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/syscalls

Comment: this directory use raw_tracepoint? /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/raw_syscalls